# How do I activate mysqli with wampserver?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I've spent over 6 hours trying to connect to `phpMyAdmin`, and would be pulling out my hair if I had any.

I downloaded `wampserver`, and have been dealing with issues. After solving about three of them, I finally got `phpMyAdmin` to pull up, but now it is giving me this error:

```
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. <a href="Documentation.html#faqmysql" target="documentation"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a>
```

I read a lot of the other solutions to this problem and have tried them. Namely the common answer seems to be to uncomment mysqli and a couple other extensions, which I have done.

After hours of trying different solutions, I am pretty stuck and could definitely use some specific answers if any are available.

I was looking at someone else's code, and I noticed that their config file was different then mine when they got it working.

Mine is linked to Windows, while theirs to their php.ini.
Is this potentially the problem, and if so how do I change it?

Here is mine:
[image]

Here is theirs: 
[image]

Also, I can run `phpMyAdmin` through my hosting, but I need to run `php` on my `localhost`. Is `phpMyAdmin` even needed to do this? I loaded a file and it came up blank, without even posting the code or anything, so this is why I assumed I needed to mess with `phpMyAdmin` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a chance that there two installations of php. If not,then check that php.ini file is loading mysqli extension.

click on the icon in the system tray, go to PHP -> PHP Extensions and make sure it is checked

else go to php.ini file any uncomment this line

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have done this, and am still not having any luck unfortunately. I did have two versions of Php installed, and I removed one, restarted wamp, and it's still giving me the error..

Comment: May be u dint install latest php5 version, which version of php have you installed?

Answer (score 0):

If you get such an error without changing any settings of wampserver, just downgrade the php version, then select the version you are using again and it will be fixed.

System tray - Wampserver PHP -> PHP version - 7.4.26 change 7.3.33
Restart all service
Again
System tray - Wampserver PHP -> PHP version - 7.3.33 change 7.4.26
fixed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).